# How do I conditionally include a file in a Sphinx 'toctree'?

Tags: python, conditional-statements, python-sphinx, toctree

I would like to include one of my files in my Sphinx TOC only when a certain tag is set, however the obvious approach fails:

```
.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 5

   index
   core
   utils
   oec
   plotting

   install
   news

   glossary

   .. only:: private_version

      todo
```

Is there a simple way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 4):

In a past I had a need to be able to compile two documentations from the same source file: a public and a private.

To succeed I had to write my own plugin (that you can find [here](https://gist.github.com/kakawait/9215487)).

When I have a file to be only on private documentation I just add this following directive on the top of the file (mandatory)

```
.. meta::
    :scope: private_version
```

**public-sample.rst (nothing special)**

```
Title
=====

A public content
```

**private-sample.rst**

```
.. meta::
    :scope: private_version

Title
=====

A private content
```

**index.rst**

```
.. toctree::
    :maxdepth: 3

    public-sample.rst
    private-sample.rst
```

As you can see on `toctree` there is the both reference, but the plugin will remove the **private-sample.rst** during compilation if you'r not building with tag `private`

So using

```
sphinx-build ... -t private_version ...
```

Will generate `toctree` like:

- public-sample.rst
- private-sample.rst

but if you build with

```
sphinx-build ... -t other ...
```

or

```
sphinx-build ...
```

the `toctree` will look like

- public-sample.rst

My plugin is not 100% perfect but I just a small piece of code a easy to understand so you can edit like you want :)

Know limitations:

limitation:

- The directive .. meta:: :scope: must be place at the top of the file (no line before)
- The directive .. meta:: :scope: must match the regexp ^.. meta::\s+:scope: ([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)
- The directive .. meta:: :scope: can manage multiple tag but you can easily update the plugin for your needs
- Plugin deviate the original use of `meta` directive docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#meta

Comment: I think you should provide a link to http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#meta and explain that you "abuse" the `meta` directive.

Comment: Would you happen to know how to get rid of all the "WARNING: toctree contains reference to nonexisting document u'private-sample.rst'" messages? I am using your script (thanks!!) to exclude many files and I get plenty of these warnings.

Comment: @calys put `:orphan:` at the top of each file causing the warning to suppress it.